# Typescript - Mapping index of array

Tags: typescript

We should be able to use `in keyof` to index an Array since the index are just numbers. In which case, the following code should work?

Does anybody have any insight into what I'm missing?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgIYCdfYCeA%20gCqIoAeqYAJmogN4DWKhAXIhrjGAOYBfANoBdAHwAKXgAcQUdngIlSASk6MhvWlUS9ErQnGCJFRMiM6nlmulRFCA5AYciBAKEZvE3xLhRQQXCQHBxMGbDBCAG43dzcgA)

```
function test 
   <array_T extends {key: string}[]>(input:array_T) : 
     {[index in keyof array_T]: array_T[index]['key']}
  
  {
    return '' as any;
  }

***ERROR***
Type '"key"' cannot be used to index type 'array_T[index]'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation/bug in TypeScript. See [microsoft/TypeScript#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995) for more information.  While mapping over an array/tuple input type [does result in an array/tuple output type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays), inside the mapped type's clause itself the compiler mistakenly thinks that `I in keyof T` is iterating over all keys of `T`, even the array methods and `length`.

For now you have to convince the compiler that `T[I]` is assignable to `T[number]`, the element type of the array.  You can use the [`Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to do this:

```
function test<T extends { key: string }[]>(input: T): {
    [I in keyof T]: Extract<T[I], T[number]>['key']
} {
    return '' as any;
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgCqJQD1TABM1EBvRAaxQE8AuRDAJxjAHNEBfAbQF0AfAAo2ABxBRG2AJSNyAKERLEPAJKI21OnGCJsfRgFFCzAIbQcavgBo9PMCAC2AIxTNBPAOQ1anvvK4KRWVmFCgQZiRPT0RTMlMwWgBuAPlFIA)